# Unable to customize CSS with mat-tab or mat-ink-bar (Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular, element, developer-tools

I've tried a number of ways to call the `mat-tab` and `mat-ink-bar` in my CSS. I have something like this HTML, for example:

```
 </div>
    <mat-card>
      <mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab label="Login">
          <app-login></app-login>
        </mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

I am working in that component's CSS to customize the style. I can go into the developer tools and modify the CSS of the element directly in the browser, but I am having difficulty calling those elements in the CSS file.

In the Style section of developer tools after clicking on that particular element, I can see that it is under `.mat-tab-header`, and I modified some of the values successfully. I cannot get it to work when I call that in the CSS file.

The element breaks down like this (hopefully this helps):

```
<mat-card class="mat-card">
  <mat-tab-group class="mat-tab-group mat-primary">
    <mat-tab-header class="mat-tab-header">
      <div class="mat-tab-header-pagination mat-tab-header-pagination-before mat-elevation-z4 mat-ripple mat-tab-header-pagination-disabled>
      <div class="mat-tab-label-container">
        <div class="mat-tab-list">
          <div class="mat-tab-labels">
            <div class="mat-tab-label mat-ripple mat-tab-label-active ng-star-inserted">
            <mat-ink-bar class="mat-ink-bar">
```

How can I correctly call these elements in the CSS so I can modify their styles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try :host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-header { } 
And if still no change, add !important.

Comment: I found using just ::ng-deep .mat-tab-header { } and !important worked out. From this, can you help me understand what my issue was? Thanks!

Comment: The default css encapsulation prevents component styles from bleeding into child components. It's by design so that components would always look the same wherever they are, and styles wouldn't accidentally collide. ::ng-deep overrides that to allow affecting children.

Another way would've been just !important in the global styles (styles.css).